# How to return a tag on calling the method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to return a tag from a method so that once I call the method the tags are returned and these tags are used to call a component.
analysisinfo is an useState array which contains the below values. These values are being passed into this method.

```
0:
cpu: true
hdd: true
id: "00000000000000000000000000000000"
ram: true 

const Populate = () => (
<>
    { 
        analysisinfo
            .filter(i => i.id !== defaultid)
            .map((i, idx) => (
                <AU props={i} instance={idx} />
            ))
     }
</>
);
```

On calling the method AU tag isn't been called and its is not been populated.

Comment: Try to verify that `analysisifno` contains what you expect it to contain.

Comment: @tromgy, Yes the one that I have mentioned above in an array.

Comment: What is the value of `defaultid`? How does the `AU` component look like? Try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).